# How to read the data present in dataset object and display using gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("URL.xml"));
```

I've read the XML file into a dataset and I want to display the data present in the dataset in form of a table??

Comment: _grid.DataSource = ds; grid.DataBind()_ It is a basic info for anyone that needs to bind a datasource in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

this way you can display the data in data set:

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds; // dataset
DataGridView1.DataMember = "TableName"; // table name you need to show
DataGridView1.DataBind()
```